# 'how' instead of 'the way'

Tags: relative-clauses

> Would his parents understand him **the way** you do?

-->

> Would his parents understand him **how** you do?

is the rephrasing above grammatically ok?

Comment: I would prefer *Would his parents understand him **as** you do?*

Answer (score -1):

Your phrase is grammatical. The adverb, 'how', means

> In what manner or way; by what means ...

(how. (n.d.) American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Fifth Edition. (2011). Retrieved September 11 2015 from http://www.thefreedictionary.com/how).